# What conditions would need to exist for another earth-like planet to experience time 4 times faster than earth?

Tags: gravity, time, relativity

I'm trying to write a story and I want it to be as scientifically plausible as possible.

By saying experiencing time 4 times faster, I mean 20 years on that planet would be 5 years on this earth. Would it's proximity to a black hole be a factor?

What if the black hole in the middle of our galaxy didn't exist?

Comment: This goes on worldbuilding, but I think the answer is, it's impossible.

Comment: Proximity to a black hole makes time pass more slowly rather than more quickly.

Comment: @user253751 You're probably right that it does, but I still think this does have something to do with physics and relativity. Right?

Comment: @DavidHammen I know. I was thinking that the earth-like planet's closest black hole would be further away from it than the black hole that is closest to us. I just want to know how far it would have to be to have that effect, and what other effects that would exist. For example the days/months/years would be longer/shorter

Comment: @BenjaminSafari I haven't done the numbers but I bet there is no place in the universe where time is more than 1% faster than it is on Earth.

Comment: You need to choose one or other: It is not to be scientifically plausible as possible that black holes in the middle of our galaxy didn't exist.

Comment: See https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=time+faster